# JOin Queryset Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

alguien pueda darme una ayuda:
Estoy tratando de llegar al resultado de esta consulta:

```
"SELECT d.id,d.orden_enterprise,d.historia_clinica,d.nombre,d.codigo_as400,d.fecha_resultados,d.cedula,d.estado,e.nombre  FROM citas_detallelaboratorio d inner join core_tiposexamenes e on d.codigo_as400 = e.codigo where estado = 'V' and tipo='L' ")
```

Pero necesito realizarla como queryset de django. Para lastima d.codigo_as400 no es llave foranea de la tabla core_tiposexamenes, y e.codigo es un campo que no es primary key, sino con esto me bastara:

```
DetalleLaboratorio.objects.filter(estado='V',tipo='L').order_by('-cita__fecha_ingreso')
```

Alguien me puede ayudar como podría realizar como queryset

Comment: Puedes agregar el modelo de Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para un buen funcionamiento creo que deberías crear los modelos de cada tabla con su respectiva foreignkey (o haberlos citado en tu pregunta si ya los creaste), por ejemplo:

```
from django.db import models


class TipoExamen(models.Model):
   codigo = models.CharField(max_length=125)

class DetalleLaboratorio(models.Model):
   tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoExamen, null=True, blank=True, related_name="detalleslaboratorio", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   orden_enterprise = models.CharField(max_length=125)
   historia_clinica = models.CharField(max_length=125)
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=125)
   fecha_resultados = models.CharField(max_length=125)
   cedula = models.CharField(max_length=125)
   estado = models.CharField(max_length=125)
```

Y luego para el queryset con los valores que has puesto en tu select, sería algo así:

```
    DetalleLaboratorio.objects.filter(estado='V',tipo__codigo='L').values("id","orden_enterprise", "historia_clinica" ,"nombre", "fecha_resultados, "cedula", "estado", "tipo__nombre").order_by('-cita__fecha_ingreso')
```

[Documentación sobre los modelos en Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#quick-example)